# web-app context and FORM ACTION attribute?

Tags: html, forms, web-applications, action, tomcat7

If a form is served from a URL http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/books/new, and the FORM.ACTION is /books/add, i get an error, "The requested resource, http://localhost:8080/books/add not available on the server". I'm using Spring 3 and Tomcat 7.

If FORM.ACTION is changed to "/mywebapp/books/add" it works fine.

I was under the impression the context is not needed, browsers will only forward to the current web-app.

Is this not right?

Answer (score 3):

The form action needs to be amended to either `/mywebapp/books/add` or `./add` or `add`

Answer (score 0):

The browser will use the path you have supplied in the `action` attribute.

Since you have `/mywebapp` at the root of your web app, you will have to include it at all times, if you are using a rooted path.

You should be able to use a relative path:

```
action="add"
```